# vuejs2 returning a list of users through axios store

Tags: vuejs2, axios

How to return a list of all users so they can be listed in a table?

Axios is working fine and a version of this works fine for bringing back a single user. I think it's returning an empty array for some reason.

```
allUsers ({commit, state}) {
  if (!state.idToken) {
    return
  }
  globalAxios.get('/users.json')
    .then(res => {
      const data = res.data
      const allUsers = []
       for (let key in data) {
         const alluser = data[key]
         user.id = key
         users.push(user)
       }
      commit('storeUser', AllUsers)
    })
    .catch(error => console.log(error))
  }
```

Script:

```
import axios from 'axios';

  export default {

    computed: {
      allUsers () {
        return !this.$store.getters.alluser ? false : this.$store.getters.alluser
      },
    },
    created () {
      this.$store.dispatch('allUsers')
    }
  }
```

HTML Template:

```
<p v-if="allUsers">allUsers: {{ allUsers }}</p>
```

Comment: What is inside of `res.data`?

Answer (score 0):

could it be the typo?

```
allUsers ({commit, state}) {
  if (!state.idToken) {
    return
  }
  globalAxios.get('/users.json')
    .then(res => {
      const data = res.data
      const allUsers = []
       for (let key in data) {
         const alluser = data[key]
         user.id = key
         users.push(user)
       }
      commit('storeUser', allUsers) // <--- lower case
    })
    .catch(error => console.log(error))
  }
```

---

to display the users...

```
<div v-if="allUsers">
  <div v-for="u in allUsers" :key="u.id">{{ u.email }}</div>
</div>
<div v-else>
  ...Loading...
</div>
```

Comment: Thankyou, I can see I am now getting back an array as expected but how do i now display the array that is returned.

my records are muti field so i get record 1 = id:1, email:me@my.com.... record 2 = id:2, email: you@your.com and so on but im really stuck on how to now make use of the returned array and display it properly....thanks

Comment: updated the answer to show they could be displayed. If you have more questions around the display of the data, you should probably start a new question though

Answer (score 0):

You are not using the variables you defined in your action. It's only a syntax problem. Fix like this:

```js
allUsers ({commit, state}) {
  if (!state.idToken) {
    return
  }
  globalAxios.get('/users.json')
    .then(res => {
      const data = res.data
      const allUsers = []
      for (let key in data) {
        const user = data[key]
        user.id = key
        allUsers.push(user)
     }
    commit('storeUser', allUsers)
  })
  .catch(error => console.log(error))
}
```